# Remove the "view" segment in a CodeIgniter url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am a newbee to CodeIgniter, I have a page which is called by http://www.example.com/pages/view/about

is it possible to just use http://www.example.com/pages/about

if yes how to do it?

thnak you for your help.

Comment: thank you guys!
I will try, the problem is I'm also a newbee in url rewriting rules!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can overwrite your any URL by htaccess

or

edit your routes.php file in Codeigniter Config Folder `(application -> config -> routes.php)`
to do this see this tutorial

[Codeigniter Route tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your route.php,

```
$route["pages/(:any)"] = "pages/view/$1"
```

Caution: You can't call other functions. Pages controller should have only one method in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try codeigniter routing http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your **routes.php**:

```
$route['pages/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1'
```

This will work for only your pages controller. For all other controllers you need to define in the same way. You can also manipulate htaccess file for this.